# Excessive length of text in the table

Tags: tables

I try to font-weight the text in the table but there accur excessive length,just like:[image]

my code:

```
\begin{table*}[!htbp]
\caption{Speech content guidance for SoHRI.}\label{tab:6}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
{| m{4.7cm} | m{1.5cm}<{\centering} | m{1.2cm}<{\centering}| m{1.4cm} <{\centering}| m{1.4cm} <{\centering}| m{1.4cm}<{\centering}|m{1.4cm}<{\centering}|}
\hline
\multirow{2}*{\textbf{Action}} & \multirow{2}*{\textbf{Ground Truth}} & \multirow{2}*{$\bar{E}_{M}$} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$L_{i}(\%)$} \\
        \cline{4-7}
        ~ & ~ & ~ & \textbf{Formal} & \textbf{Relaxed}& \textbf{Sad} & \textbf{Negligent} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

but my another table didn't font-weight the text can wrap automatically,that's what I confused, I just want like the following one :
[image]

Hope someone could help, thanks a lot..!

Comment: Make a complete, small example that can be used to test the issue.

Comment: Does using `\multirow{2}{=}{\textbf{Ground Truth}}` solve your problem? The `=` in the second pair of curly braces to indicates that the width of the column in which the \multirow entry is set should be used.

Comment: why `m{1.5cm}<{\centering}`  rather than `>{\centering}m{1.5cm}` the form you have used is rather odd and only centres the last paragraph and doesn't centre anything if a blank line is at the end of the cell.

Comment: I use the "=" and it wrap suceefully but not centring...anyway, thanks for your help!@leandriis  @David Carlisle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

see if the following is what you looking for:

[image]

beside suggestion given in above comments i suggest to use `tabularx` table environment and define two new column type (based on `X`) for centering and left aligned cells' contents:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[htbp]
\caption{Speech content guidance for SoHRI.}
\label{tab:6}
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\hsize=0.40\hsize}L|
                              >{\hsize=0.12\hsize}C|
                                                  c|
                         *{4}{>{\hsize=0.12\hsize}C|}}
    \hline
\multirow{2}{=}{\centering\textbf{Action}}
    &   \multirow{2}{=}{\centering\textbf{Ground Truth}}
        &   \multirow{2}*{$\bar{E}_{M}$}
            &   \multicolumn{4}{c|}{$L_{i}(\%)$}    \\
    \cline{4-7}
    &   &   & \textbf{Formal} & \textbf{Relaxed} & \textbf{Sad} & \textbf{Negligent} \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @berlinpand, you are welcome!